# find the column identity in a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, identity

Can someone know if there is a way to find the column name that has the identity property in an sql server table

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use sys.columns for this quite easily.

```
select * 
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('YourTableNameHere')
    AND is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to looking it up in the metadata, you can use `$identity` to refer to an identity column. For example, given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (some_random_name INT IDENTITY, other_column VARCHAR(20));
```

...you can use:

```
SELECT $identity, other_column FROM test_table;
```

to bring back `some_random_name, other_column`.

(`$identity` replaces the deprecated `IDENTITYCOL` of earlier versions of SQL Server.)

Comment: I don't really agree that this is an answer to the question most likely, but +1 for teaching me something new. https://www.mindstick.com/blog/358/usage-of-rowguid-and-identity-in-sql-server

Comment: @shriop Yeah, I just figured it might be a useful answer to *someone* who'd be reading the question at some point, rather than being the best answer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution in [this link](https://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/fck-it-i-am-going-to-search-all-tables-all-collumns/) to search the whole database for a specific value, which can be a username you know exists "somewhere" in the database. 
It gives you the table and column name where that specific value exists.

Comment: Umm...this has nothing to do with the question. The OP is looking for a way to determine which column in a table has the Identity property set to true.

Comment: Oh sorry I though he was looking to find which which column in which table hold identity related information. My bad.

Comment: Heh I figured it was a misunderstanding of the question. No biggie.